# Clicking on UIImage in prototype cell to perform segue doesn't work

Tags: ios6, uistoryboard, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I'm developing an app in xcode for ios6 with a storyboard. I have an TableView with prototype cells. In every cell is an UIImageView. I try to perform a segue on tap on the image.

To do this, I made the Image User Interaction Enabled. The I dragged a Tap Gesture Recognizer on the Image and wired up the segue to another view. I get the following error on my storyboard:
Illegal Configuration: Gesture recognizers cannot be used on prototype objects.

My questions are:
Am I doing something wrong?
What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a UIButton instead of a UIImageView to link that segue.